Can an Ideal Lever Balance in a Non-Horizontal Position?
I recently came across an interesting question while reading Feynman's Lectures on Physics. In chapter 4–2 "Gravitational potential energy," there's an illustration that made me wonder about the behavior of an ideal lever.

My question is: Can an ideal lever balance in a non-horizontal position? It seems theoretically possible, as it doesn't appear to violate any physical principles. However, in reality, we mostly see levers balancing in a horizontal position. This discrepancy puzzles me: Why do we typically observe levers in a horizontal balance state in practical scenarios? Are there any special constraints or practical difficulties that prevent levers from balancing in non-horizontal positions?
I would appreciate any insights or explanations.

We see practical levers balance in the middle because they are not ideal.  An ideal lever will balance in any position.
The key to such a lever setup is that the sum of the torques about the fulcrum must be 0.  On both left and right sides, you end up with a $\cos \theta$ term which cancels out.  If you perturb the ideal lever by x degrees, it decreases the torque of both left and right sides by the same amount.
The key is that no lever is truly uniform.  the fulcrum has some curvature to it.  As the balance tips to one direction (say, the left), the fulcrum moves in that direction slightly.  This changes the balance of the torques.  This leads to there being a stable point at some lever angle.  This stable point does not exist in the ideal case.
When the lever is perfectly horizontal, that corresponds to some fulcrum position, given the roundness of the fulcrum.  We traditionally balance scales such that they read correctly when the fulcrum is in this state.  You could make a scale which balances at, say, a 20 degree angle.  It would just be unusual.

The balance of a lever on a central fulcrum is assured in any
angular position, if the center of mass of that lever is at the
center of rotation.   Those levers that have a fulcrum at one
endpoint instead of in the center, are not likely to suit that
condition.
So, the answer is yes and no, depending on the nature of the 'ideal'
of leverage being considered.
It is not unusual for a delicate balance to be designed with the beam center of mass adjustable by a vertical-from-pivot adjustable mass; that makes
the balance adjustable for pans-and-beam to have the center of mass very close to the pivot (for maximum sensitivity) but not exactly (so
the return-to-level with weight adjusted can occur swiftly).
